# Background image not appearing in Search Results

Tags: html, search

I have an instant search set up at http://althedge.xyz   I would like to use an image as the background for the search results but I don't know how.  Is there a way to do this with this type of code?  If so, please show me how.  Thanks

```
//set up the list
    $(this.list)
        .css({
                listStyleType: "none",
                display: "none", 
                boxShadow: "1px 1px 5px #888888",
                borderRadius: "10px",
                background: "#XXXXXX",
                border: "1px solid blue",
                margin: "0",
                padding: "0"


            })
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but to make a background image apply to a specific id, class, or html element tag, you can do this in the CSS:

```
.yourClass {
    background-image: url("pathToFile/image.jpg")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.back_bg {
    background: url('../img/images.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Would that put the image just in the search box results background?

Comment: You add the above in css. In the search box, if it is a `<div>` or `<article>` or any other html element you just add `<div class="back_bg">` I used `<div>` but it can be anything including table or even body.